# Load more .json in different divs html with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I have a div that load a content from a .json file with angular.js

This is the code:

```
<div class="pbox" id="div1">
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController">

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                {{ x.Name}}
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                {{ x.Details}}
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                {{ x.Composizione}}
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                {{ x.moreDetails}}
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                <img ng-src="{{x.photo1}}"/>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                <img ng-src="{{x.photo2}}"/>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                <img ng-src="{{x.photo3}}"/>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                <img ng-src="{{x.photo4}}"/>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <script>
        $scope.names = {}
        function customersController($scope, $http) {

            $http.get("assets/data/five.json")

                    .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.names = response;
                    });

        }
    </script>
</div>

<div class="pbox" id="div2">
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController">

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names_two">
                {{ x.Name}}
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names_two">
                {{ x.Details}}
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names_two">
                {{ x.Composizione}}
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names_two">
                {{ x.moreDetails}}
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names_two">
                <img ng-src="{{x.photo1}}"/>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names_two">
                <img ng-src="{{x.photo2}}"/>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names_two">
                <img ng-src="{{x.photo3}}"/>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names_two">
                <img ng-src="{{x.photo4}}"/>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <script>
        $scope2.names_two = {}
        function customersController($scope, $http) {

            $http.get("assets/data/five.json")

                    .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.names_two = response;
                    });

        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Now i wont populate another div with the same fields but with the contents of another .json, not five.json.
There is a way to do this? I tried to duplicate all but the second doesen't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the contents of `$scope.names`. If you want to display both on your screen, you should just copy paste the content, and use another object name.

You should also initiate the object at the start of your controller :

```
$scope.names = {}
```

This can prevent bugs in the future. Your browser is faster than your server, so `$scope.names` doesn't exist until you get your data from the server, or in your case local machine. Which will cause a error.

Your update fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p7exvdmf/16/

Comment: I tried to duplicate (i have edit the code in the first post) but now i doesen't show nothing also in the first div...:(

Comment: You have to call the second scope variable i.e. $scope.names_two, not $scope2.names; $scope2.something will give you errors, since $scope2 doesn't exist in angular. Also, define $scope.names = {} inside of the controller, not before.

Comment: i've edited but no...doesen't work, are you sure? :)

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle for me ? I will have a look at your code.

Comment: i've edited adding <li ng-repeat="x in names_two"> and  $scope.names_two = response; but nothing. if i delete the content of the second div the first works, i dont understand really. i try to create a fiddle but i dont know where put the json...

Comment: Copy paste the JSON from the file into the fiddle as raw data. Or create some test data.

Comment: I updated the answer, working fine now. You were using 2 controllers with the same name.. That will give errors. Use it like I did, wrap everything in one div, and give that the name of your controller. Also changed X in the second ng-repeat to Y.

Comment: No problem, if you have anymore questions, please feel free to ask them. Upvote will be appreciated :)